# Counting the number of small letter words in a string - c programming

Tags: c, string

I need some help to write a function that will count the number of small letter words in a string.

For the purpose of this assignment, a "word" is defined to be a sequence of the only small letter (between `char >= 'a'` and  `char =< 'z'`) without any other characters

```
int numberOfSmallLetterWords(char* str)
```

For example:

```
numberOfSmallLetterWords(" it is a sMall World after all! ")
```

returns the value: 4

“all!” Doesn’t consider word

Comment: For the string `" it is a sMall World after all! "` I assume the last `"all!"` doesn't match the criteria because of the `'!'` at the end?

Comment: As for possible way to solve your problem, look into [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) and [`islower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/islower).

Comment: If you wanna implement without standard functions. Just iterate through your string and increase a counter when some criteria match.

Comment: Cool. Your classmates and professor are there to provide "from-scratch" help. Stack Overflow isn't.

Comment: The functionality of both `strtok` and `islower` are easy to recreate. Especially if you limit yourself (like only tokenizing space-delimited "words", and using only ASCII encoding).

Comment: I agree with Some programmer dude, that by your definition "all!" does not qualify as a word.  I suggest a solution using `strtok` and the regular expression `^[a-z][a-z][a-z]$` using the `regex.h` library.

Comment: Frankly guy is it useless to use strtok for something so trivial

Comment: @bruno it can not be same trivial if we have more delimiters. Here `!` is one of them

Comment: @P__J__ ! is not like a space else the result is 5 rather than 4, ! is not a delimiter and "all!" is not a word. Words are "it is a after"

Comment: "it's a Small World after all! Sherman brothers wrote ..."

Comment: "char > 'a' and  char < 'z'" implies `"a"` is not a word.  Did you mean "char >= 'a' and  char <= 'z'".

Comment: @Ron Fybish, please clarify: if `"all!"` a 4 letter _word_?  Should it count as a _small letter word_?

Comment: @chux the answer is 4 so "all!" is not a word. The example is clear, this is enough rare to underline that ^^

Comment: @bruno The question was directed to Ron Fybish

Comment: “all!” Is not consider a small letters word @chux

Comment: @chux you right! “char>=‘a’ and char<=‘z’”

Comment: @RonFybish my answer respect your definition of a word, and it very fast

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  you’re right I edited that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A proposal, very fast because the string is run through only one time and there is no dynamic (de)allocation in the heap. See comments in the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int numberOfSmallLetterWords(char* str)
{
  int nWords = 0;
  int inWord = 0;
  int inSpaces = 1; /* not 0 to allow a word to start at the first character */

  while (*str) {
    if (islower(*str)) {
      /* compatible with a word */
      if (inSpaces) {
        /* start a potential new word */
        inSpaces = 0;
        inWord = 1;
      }
      /* else nothing change:
         - if we was in a word we are still
         - if we was not in word nor spaces we are still in none of them 
      */
    }
    else if (isspace(*str)) {
      if (inWord) {
        /* spaces after a potential word validates it */
        nWords += 1;
        inWord = 0;
      }
      inSpaces = 1;
    }
    else
      /* not in spaces nor in word */
      inWord = inSpaces = 0;
    str += 1;
  }

  /* warning do not forget to count a possible word at the end */
  return (inWord) ? (nWords + 1) : nWords;
}

int main()
{
  printf("%d\n", numberOfSmallLetterWords(" it is a sMall World after all! "));
  return 0;
}
```

Execution :

```
4
```

and under valgrind :

```
==9376== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==9376== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==9376== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==9376== Command: ./a.out
==9376== 
4
==9376== 
==9376== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9376==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9376==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==9376== 
==9376== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==9376== 
==9376== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9376== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

---

If you do not want to use the *ctype islower* and *isspace* :

```
int islower(char c)
{
  return ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z')); 
}

int isspace(char c)
{
  switch (c) {
  case ' ':
  case '\t':
  case '\n':
  case '\r':
    /* may be more cases */
    return 1;
  default:
    return 0;
  }
}
```

warning these definitions are less portable than the ctype version

Comment: A bit naive implementation . Only spaces counted as delimiter. What about: "hello,m dear Firend"

Comment: I just follow the question, "hello,m dear Firend" : 1 word

Comment: @P__J__  Even I code since 35 years I do not have the pretension to be more than a beginner because there are always new things to learn. And you ? ;-)

Comment: Still waiting for the more decent implementation. The test string is: `"!;.!I want;;to,,counT:,this oNe    "` Delimiters `"!;., "` With your experience it should not take long.

Comment: @P__J__ ? I have nothing to change to return 0 as expected

Answer (score 0):

```
int all_lower(const char *str)
{
    while(*str)
       if(!islower(*str++)) return 0;
    return 1;
}

size_t wlcount(const char *str, const char *del)
{
    size_t count = 0;
    char *copy = strdup(str);
    char *word;

    if(copy)
    {
        word = strtok(copy, (char *)del);
        while(word)
        {
            if(*word) count += all_lower(word);
            word = strtok(NULL, del);
        }
        free(copy);
    }
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%zu\n", wlcount(" it is a sMall World after all! ", " !"));
}
```

Comment: this is an expensive implementation, you duplicate the string and you read it several times : first time to duplicate, an other by strtok and again each potential words. Sorry but I prefer my solution ^^

Comment: Duplication is a safety measure.

Comment: you also returns 5 rather than 4 as expected (I know the fix is easy ^^)

Comment: Of course while you use strtok, but is like to use a bulldozer to crush a fly ^^ (just my 2 cents) Anyway that has the advantage to speck about strtok and can help the OP to learn about it :-)

Comment: @bruno - 1. it, 2. is, 3. a, 4 after, 5 all - correct answer. Look at the second parameter (delimiters)

Comment: @bruno waiting for your effective solution the sentence `"!;.!I want;;to,,counT:,this oNe      "` Delimiters `"!;., "`

Comment: Damned, it was already slow and you added a _strlen_ to again read a potential word. No pity for the CPU ? ^^

Comment: @bruno - waiting for your a bit more decent (not naive) solution.

Comment: DV? Any explanation?

Comment: I was also DV, what to say ? I move to something else, have a good day ;-)

Comment: @bruno  thank you very much bruno! But I need to implement this function only with <string.h> and <stdio.h> without allocated memory.

Comment: @bruno i need to implement this function without any other functions

Comment: @bruno it will be a pleasure! I need this in the simplest way